# (Incomparable Types: String and Pedido) Comparar una entrada en JTextField con la base de datos en JPA

Tags: java, java-swing, hibernate, jpa

Intento hacer una manera con que el valor digitado por el usuario pueda ser comparado con los datos de una coluna de una base de datos o una JTable (no se qual es mejor para ese fin), por ejemplo: cuando la entrada del numero de controle ser: 123456 y en la coluna numControle de la base loja tener algun dato con ese valor el no deja el usuario insertar. Acá sigues mi solución:

```js
public class MySQLPedidoDAO implements PedidoDAO {

    //null pointer exception pois esse campo estava inicializado como null
    public ConnectionFactory cf;
    
    public MySQLPedidoDAO(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        this.cf = cf;
    }
    
    /*... algunos metodos del crud JPA...*/

/*
@Override
    public List<Pedido> getNumControle(){
       cf = new ConnectionFactory();
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
       Query consulta = cf.createEm().createQuery("select numControle from Pedido p");
       List <Pedido> pedidos = consulta.getResultList();
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
       cf.close();
       return pedidos;
    }*/

@Override
    public Integer<Pedido> getNumControle(){
       cf = new ConnectionFactory();
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
       Query consulta = cf.createEm().createQuery("select numControle from Pedido p");
       List <Integer> pedidos = consulta.getResultList();
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
       cf.close();
       return pedidos;
    }
    
}
```

ViewPedidos:

```js
public class ViewPedidos extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    private DAOManager manager;
    private PedidoModel model;
    private MySQLPedidoDAO mspdao;
    private MySQLClienteDAO mscdao;
    private MySQLProdutoDAO msprdao;
    private List<Produto> produtos;
    private List<Pedido> pedidos;
    private Pedido ped;
    private Produto pro;
    private boolean editavel;

    /**
     * @return the ped
     */
    public Pedido getPed() {
        return ped;
    }

    /**
     * @param ped the ped to set
     */
    public void setPed(Pedido ped) {
        this.ped = ped;
    }

    /**
     * @return the editavel
     */
    public boolean isEditavel() {
        return editavel;
    }



public void inserirDados(Pedido ped) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
        mspdao = new MySQLPedidoDAO(cf);
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
        //Acá recupero los valores de la función en una lista
        List<Integer> pedido = mspdao.getNumControle();


    /* ... inserciones en JTextField arriba ... */
        if(tfDataCad.getText().length() == 0){
        ped.setDataCadastro(date);
        } else {
        ped.setDataCadastro(new java.sql.Date(((java.util.Date) tfDataCad.getValue()).getTime()));
        } 
        ped.setNomeProduto(cbNomeProduto.getSelectedItem().toString());
        ped.setNumControle(Integer.parseInt(tfNumControle.getText()));
 for (int i = 0; i < pedido.size(); i++) {
       // Pedido get = pedido.get(i);
Integer get = pedido.get(i);
/* Error abajo, Incomparable types: String and Integer */
        if(tfNumControle.getText() == get){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Inserção não realizada, Numero de controle já cadastrado", "Cadastro de Pedidos", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
          //insertar
        }
    }
}
```

Y el stacktrace:

```js
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.exemplo.model.Pedido
 at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.inserirDados(ViewPedidos.java:549)
 at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.btInserirActionPerformed(ViewPedidos.java:409)
 at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos.access$300(ViewPedidos.java:51)
 at com.exemplo.view.ViewPedidos$4.actionPerformed(ViewPedidos.java:283)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Aún soy iniciante en JPA, con resultSet() me recuerdo que es diferente apenas poniendo el metodo rs.next(), ahí hice un for para percorrer la lista pero no estás comparando y retorna ese error de incomparación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar recorrerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
for(Pedido pedGet: pedido){
//Aquí obtienes tu valores
int numeroN = pedGet.getValor();
//Y lo comparas para que no lo deje insertar
if(numControle == numeroN){
//No inserto
}else{
//Inserto
}
}
```

Edito mi respuesta:

No puedes comparar un Integer con un String

```
if(tfNumControle.getText() == get){
```

Debes cambiar tu get a un String y compararlos con el equals, de la siguiente forma:

```
 if(tfNumControle.getText().equals(String.valueOf(get))){
```

Suerte!

Comment: Yo hice de esa manera @5frags:

 `for(Pedido pedGet: pedido) { 
//Aquí obtienes tu valores 
int numero = pedGet.getNumControle(); 
//Y lo comparas para que no lo deje insertar 
if(tfNumControle == numero) { 
//No inserto 
}else{ 
//Inserto 
} 
} `

El está retornando el error en esa línea: `for(Pedido pedGet: pedido)` y en ese `if(tfNumControle == numero)` el retorna incomparable types de nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Estas mal en tu consulta **select numControle from Pedido p**  esto te regresa datos de tipo entero no de tu tipo objeto **Pedido**, tienes de dos opciones cambiar tu consulta a si:

`select p from Pedido p`

Esto te regresara la consulta a tu tipo de objeto **pedido**.

o

Recibir esa lista de enteros de la siguiente manera:

```
List <Integer> pedidos = consulta.getResultList();
```

pero esto implica que tu método retorne datos de tipo entero.

```
@Override
    public List<Integer> getNumControle(){
       cf = new ConnectionFactory();
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
       Query consulta = cf.createEm().createQuery("select numControle from Pedido p");
       List <Integer> pedidos = consulta.getResultList();
       cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
       cf.close();
       return pedidos;
    }
```

Comment: Yo modifiqué algunos campos de mi publicación comentando los errores y añadiendo las correciones ahora, mira

Comment: Acabé de hacer de esa segunda manera que tu escribió la función, quiero apenas recuperar los valores de una solo columna de la tabla y comparar con un dato de la `JTextField`, en el caso de la primera yo recogería todos los valores verdad? Y en for yo hice así no se se estás cierto: `for (int i = 0; i < pedido.size(); i++) { Integer get = pedido.get(i); if(tfNumControle.getText() == get){ // no inserir } else { // inserir } }` Pero en el if ocurre `Incomparable types: String and Integer` nuevamente

Comment: Entonces cambia el tipo de retorno a un String, quedando String valor = String.valueOf(pedido.get(i)); Y en tu if quedando de la siguiente manera: if(valor.equals(tfNumControle.getText.trim())){ //Aquí lo demás de tu lógica}

Comment: Ahora logré!! finalmente la logica funcionó, yo no sabia del metodo trim() desde inicio, estaba acá en el inicio intentando varias formas por la tentativa y error, muchas gracias!!

Comment: @VictorG. me alegro, podrías poner como respuesta correcta!